# How could I dim the external display brightness in Plasma 5?

Tags: linux, display, display-settings, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

I'm using Plasma 5 for GNU/Linux in a *desktop PC* box. I would need a way to dim display brightness, but I have absolutely no idea where to start looking for it. Whatever you come up with, CLI solutions are welcome, but it's not necessary for me to have a CLI solution.

Answer (score 7):

Not tried with external monitor, but it seems you can:

1. List your displays:

   ```
   xrandr -q | grep -w connected

   HDMI1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   ```
2. Using the name(s) listed, set the brightness:

   ```
   xrandr --output HDMI1  --brightness 1.0
   ```

(from [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=127102))

Comment: It is working for the `VGA-0` display (yay!) but not for the `DVI-D-0` and `HDMI-0` displays. In any case, thank you **very** much!

Comment: It works with `DisplayPort-0`

Comment: Works, but resets the current colour temperature set by Night Colour back to a piercing blue 

Answer (score 1):

In the KDE workspace this is easily done via the "Battery" widget/plasmoid (this widget auto-hides when the battery is filled up, so you may have to search it a bit):

[image]

Comment: My understanding is that this brightness control only works with laptop screens (it may not even appear on a desktop system).  That's probably why it's bundled with battery power management.

Comment: Can you force this if there is no battery? If not, then I can't accept the answer, because this was for a desktop box.

Comment: It does not work with an external monitor.