# How could I dim the display brightness of a desktop PC while using Plasma 5 on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, desktop-computer, display-settings, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

I'm using Plasma 5 for GNU/Linux in a **desktop PC** box. I would need a way to dim display brightness, but I have absolutely no idea where to start looking for it. Whatever you come up with, CLI solutions are welcome, but it's not necessary for me to have a CLI solution.

This is how the `Battery and Brightness` *plasmoid* is rendering:

[image]

I was expecting the *plasmoid* to be provisioned with a **`Display Brightness` slider**, but it **is not there. Is there a way to bring it appearing?** Should I open issue at KDE?

Comment: could you not DIM the actual monitor itself using its own menu options?

Comment: [In case you were asking about manipulating hardware controls](https://i2.wp.com/bobmartens.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Multiple-Monitors-8.jpg).

Comment: @TiO, there are scenarios where adjusting the monitor isn't the best solution.  For example, multi-booting.  If each OS is adjusted, you don't need to readjust the monitor when you change OS.

Comment: @uprego, that picture in your comment is just bragging.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 the need is for a PC set with only three displays. The picture for me is just convenience multi media stock extracted from the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to modify monitor brightness over HDMI, or any other display connector AFAIK.

The next best thing is to use a color management profile to dim the display using software. This results in worse color accuracy and won't work when not in the Desktop Environment, but when you have 8 monitors it seems like your only choice.

Use [lprof](http://lprof.sourceforge.net/) to create a color profile with the brightness you want, you should be able to ignore most of the process and just use the defaults.

After creating a color profile, you can use [oyranos-monitor](https://userbase.kde.org/Color_Management) to change between it and the normal color profile via the command line.

Comment: This answer is poor, it does not provide easy to follow instructions. I cannot add any additional information because I am not using a GNU/Linux distro right now.

Comment: I don't hang around superuser.com so much as previously, enough to know which are the current recommended standards for answers, but still I find that comment over self deprecation. This way to go is indeed some work, specially given I can solve the problem turning on the ambient lights of the room, but there is a lot of value in pointing to the best available resources and ways and even if there was an easier way to go there is a lot of value in pointing any useful resource and high level recipe. To me this is looking a lot worth trying.

Comment: OK, I understand you now. I am turning on the lights.

Comment: If you knew how to fix [this](https://superuser.com/a/1273038/174140) for my PC that would be awesome.

Comment: What step in that solution aren't you able to follow? If you can set the brightness for one of the monitors then you can probably write a simple bash script to change them all at once. What is your output of `xrandr -q | grep -w connected`?

Answer (score 1):

Some monitors have DDC/CI support, which allows you to send your monitor commands over the display cable.
You'll want to install `ddcutil` and by running `ddcutil detect` can see if your monitor gets detected.

In order to control the brightness via Plasma you can use the [Display Brightness](https://github.com/davidhi7/ddcci-plasmoid) widget. This can be installed via the built-in plasma widget search but some setup is needed after installation, which is best explained by the Github page. Then you can add the widget to your dock.